# jaxrs-api VS jsr311-api VS javax.ws.rs-api VS jersey-core VS jaxrs-ri

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs, jsr, jsr311

I have googled around quite a bit still am confused as to what each of the above exactly mean.

Here is my understanding of it:

- **jaxrs-api** : contains only api. No implementation. But how is it different from JSR311
- **jsr311-api** : JSR311 it is a specification request. Which means it is supposed to be a document. Why then is it a jar?
- **javax.ws.rs-api**:  Is it an implementation?
- **jersey-core**(/jersey client): Is an implementation of JSR311.

I downloaded each jar and tried to decompile and see what is inside it, but I am only able to find interfaces in all of them and not the implementation.

I am facing these questions in the context of duplicate warnings generated by maven shade plugin, and need proper understanding of the above to figure out which ones to exclude and why.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I'll first get to the question

> "JSR311 it is a specification request. Which means it is supposed to be a document. Why then is it a jar?"

Except the last (`jersey-core`), all those jars are "specification" jars. The JAX-RS (as well as many other Java) specifications define contracts (or interfaces) that implementators should implement the specified behavior for.

So basically all the classes specified in the specification should be in the jar as contracts. End users of the jars can use them for the contracts. but there is no implementation. You need to have an actually implementation to run the application, though the spec API jar is enough to *compile* a complete JAX-RS compliant application.

For example, if we have one of those spec API jars on the classpath, we can author an entire JAX-RS application and compile it, but in order to run it, if we don't have the actual implementation, we need to deploy to a server that has the actual implementation of that spec version, for example JBoss or Glassfish

---

- **jaxrs-api** - This is [RESTeasy's](http://resteasy.jboss.org/) packaging of the spec. It is not the official spec jar, but it does adhere to the spec contracts. RESTeasy uses this jar for the entire spec line, i.e. 1.x - current. Though the jar does change internals to adhere to the different JAX-RS versions.
- **jsr311-api** - This is the official spec jar for the JAX-RS 1.x line.
- **javax.ws.rs-api** - This is the official spec jar for the JAX-RS 2.x line.
- **jersey-core** - This is a partial implementation of the spec. The rest of the implementation is contained inside other Jersey jars. Note that in earlier versions of Jersey, they actually packaged the JAX-RS spec APIs into this jar. It wasn't until later that Jersey started using the official spec jars.
- **jaxrs-ri** - This is the complete Jersey 2.x implementation packaged into one jar. The "ri" mean *reference implementation*, which is what Jersey is: the JAX-RS reference implementation. If you are not using a dependency manager like Maven, you might want to just use this single jar instead of having to use all the separate jars that Jersey comes with.

**Other Resources**

- [Java API for RESTful Services (JAX-RS)](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/) to read details of the different spec versions.
- [Complete implementation for RESTeasy distribution](http://sourceforge.net/projects/resteasy/files/Resteasy%20JAX-RS/). RESTeasy 3.x line if the JAX-RS 2.x implementation, and RESTeast 2.x/1.x id for the JAX-RS 1.x line
- [Complete distribution of Jersey implementation](https://jersey.java.net/download.html). You can find the JAX-RS 2.x implementation in the "Jersey JAX-RS 2.0 RI bundle" link at the top of the page. There is also at the bottom links to the Jersey 1.x line distribution, which adheres to the JAX-RS 1.x spec.

Also note that though different implementation adhere to the spec, each implementation has its own set of extra features. To learn more you should go through the documentation of the different implementation. The three most popular implementations are [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html), [RESTeasy](http://resteasy.jboss.org/docs.html), and [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So JSR311 is the 'Speification Request'; its corresponding 'Specification API' is jsr311-api; And these and they form the JAX-RS 1.x line.  Now, JSR339 is the next 'Specification Request'; its 'Specification API' is 'javax.ws.rs-api' and they form JAX-RS 2.x line. Am i correct? If so, is there an overlap between JAX-RS 1.x and JAX-RS 2.x lines? Would they give a 'maven shade duplicate class warning' if used together? Out of jsr311-api, javax.ws.rs-api, and jaxrs-api is there a best one to use?

Comment: That's pretty much the gist of it. And yes are are overlapping classes. 2.x really just adds on to 1.x. I can't think of anything off the top of my head that was removed in 2.x.

Comment: I mean it really depends on your needs. I personally prefer to use the 2.x line, simply because I use Jersey 2, which has a bunch of features, but if you want to compares just the standard API, 2.x has filters and interceptors, async support, bean validation, and probably more things I can't think of right now

Comment: Also note that if you are using Maven, you rarely ever have to have an explicit dependency on any of the spec jars. Whatever implementation you are using will pull it in. If you are deploying to an EE server, and you wan to stick strictly to the spec (to stay portable), then you should only need the javaee-api jar. Also note that if you are using a 2.x implementation and you have a 1.x jar on the classpath, you are likely to get NuSuchMethodErrors. The major API versions are not compatible.

Comment: I am using maven, and these jars are being brought in transitively by my direct dependencies. I am not sure why my direct dependencies are pulling in the spec jars since you said they don't need to.. Anyway the maven shade plugin has warnings saying that it has duplicate classes from these jars. So trying to add exclusions on as many as I can to get rid of them/warnings. Your answer helps me. Thanks.

Comment: Your app won't run if you exclude all of them. Whatever implementation you are actually using, whichever one _that_ implementation pulls in, that is the one you should keep.

Comment: "It wasn't until later that [Jersey] starting using the official spec jars." It would be very useful if you could include the first version number(s) that no longer include the spec APIs. This way, people could fix old projects by moving the dependency version "just enough".

Comment: Note that the JAX-RS 2.x line has moved to `jakarta.ws.rs-api`, starting with 2.1.2.  3.0.0 has also been released, and no longer features Jersey as the fallback implementation.