# How to port Apache CXF based REST API to Jersey based REST API?

Tags: web-services, jersey, jax-rs, cxf, restlet

In one of my projects we have written REST API based on the **Jersey REstful** WebFramework. In some situations we might want to convert those JERSEY based REST API to the Apache CXF.

If all REST APIs (means written Interfaces and their implementation) are working fine with Jersey RESTFul Framework, then will just replacing the framework (e.g. possible jars, dependencies on POM) to Apache CXF work ?

What are the major things a developer should consider on such a porting?, Is my question relevant ? (My past experience related to the C++ system side where we ported APIs to different platform e.g. BSD Sockets API, pThread APIs. If all of these Jersey,Apache CXF,Restlet following same JAX-RS specification then porting should work ?)

Comment: Configuration and features are different for both frameworks. There _are_ standard features and configurations which are mentioned in the spec. If you followed the spec to the T, then you shouldn't have much trouble porting. If you have used a bunch of implementation specific features and configurations, then it's very difficult to know where even to start. The easiest way to find out if you app is fully JAX-RS compliant as far as classes used, you can simply remove all the jars and only add the JAX-RS API jar. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32109009/2587435). See if it compiles

Comment: With configuration it's a little more difficult to determine, as configuration done with web.xml is not compiled. For more information as to what _is_ standardized, I would refer to the actual [specification](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/)