# Fixing conflicting classes in Jetty9 hosted app

Tags: java, hadoop, jersey-2.0, jetty-9

I have a Jersey-2 based web service with a dependency on [Hadoop-HDFS](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.7.3).  Hadoop-HDFS, itself has a dependency on Jersey-1.  A conflict is arising as bother jerseys define `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`.  On my local machine, things "work" because Jersey2 is first in the classpath, but when I deploy to another machine, things break because Jersey-1 is first.  It would be great if Jetty had a way to give precedence to Jersey-2, but my research turned up no options for doing this.  Is there a way?

I cannot exclude the transitive Jersey-1 dependency outright, as it breaks the hadoop client.

Comment: You could try to exclude just the 1.x spec from [javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api) because the 2.x spec from [javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api) should be (mostly?) a superset and sufficient. Those 2 should be the ones providing the conflicting classes (unless early version of jersey2 according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106428/jaxrs-api-vs-jsr311-api-vs-javax-ws-rs-api-vs-jersey-core )

Comment: I tried to exclude the 1.x spec but got more runtime errors upon instantiating an HDFS FileSystem for reading from.  I concluded this couldn't be done reliably and split my Jetty service in two, since class-paths aren't shared.