# Getting the error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;

Tags: java, rest, maven, pom.xml, jersey-2.0

There is some version mismatch in the jersey jars but I am not able to find which one is causing this issue. I've checked the posts dealing with the same issue but I am not able to resolve it. Whenever I try to access any of my REST endpoints, I get the runtime error mentioned in the title: NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map.

```
               <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0.1</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
                    <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
                    <version>0.99</version>
                </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.9.1</version>
            </dependency>
```

The dependency:tree output:

```
        +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:4.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.owlike:genson:jar:0.99:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20180813:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz-jobs:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.22:compile
[INFO] +- io.swagger:swagger-jaxrs:jar:1.5.22:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-core:jar:1.5.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.22:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:27.0.1-android:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:2.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:jaxrs-api:jar:2.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scannotation:scannotation:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.1.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.0.0.Beta4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.wordnik:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.3-M1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.wordnik:swagger-models:jar:1.5.3-M1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:0.17.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.9.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO]    \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.9:compile
```

Comment: Well, have a look at where that class is defined and in what version that method is present. It seems as if [`getProperties()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html#getProperties--) has been added in JavaEE 7 so you need to check which of your dependencies require JavaEE 7 and whether your server supports that.

Comment: That version of Genson is old and uses Jersey 1.x ([which packaged the JAX-RS 1.x classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32109009/2587435)). I don't see anything it could be but that.